# Decimal <--> Two's Complement <--> Hex conversion

Tags: hex, decimal, twos-complement

I'm wondering if I get a question like:

> "Convert a decimal number to two's complement, then give your answer in Hex".

Is the path below, how one would do it?

Decimal number: -23

23 = 00010111 = in hex 17 = -17

-23 = 11101001 = in hex E9

So to convert it to Hex would the answer be -17 or E9?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `-17` has no relevance here, since according to your task, you have to return the two's complement as HEX and that is `E9`.

Your conversion path in general looks correct to me.

1. DEC to BIN without the sign:

   - 23 → 0001 0111
2. Negate the BIN string:

   - 0001 0111 → 1110 1000
3. Add *1* to the negated BIN result:

   - 1110 1000 + 0000 0001 → 1110 1001
4. Verify the correct two's complement calculation:

   - -128 + 64 + 32 + 8 + 1 = -23 → correct
5. Convert final BIN string to HEX:

   - 1110 1001 → 0xE9